# How to search input with a name attribute that has index inbetween with jquery efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts-1

I have JSP code like this:

```
<% int idx=0; %>
<logic:iterate id="emp" name="myForm" property="myList" indexId="xdi">
<tr class="myClass">
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="emp[<%=idx%>].compKey.id" />
        <input type="hidden" name="emp[<%=idx%>].compKey.joinDate" />
        <input type="hidden" name="emp[<%=idx%>].compKey.address" />
        <input type="hidden" name="emp[<%=idx%>].compKey.house.address" />
        <input type="hidden" name="emp[<%=idx%>].name" />
        <input type="hidden" name="emp[<%=idx%>].fakeaddress" />
        <input type="hidden" name="emp[<%=idx%>].address" />
    </td>
</tr>
<% idx++; %>
</logic:iterate>
```

I want to search and iterate the input tag with name ="emp[..].address" with jQuery. If I tried this:

```
$('tr.myClass input[name$=address]').each(function(index){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

It will also iterate the input tag with name="emp[..].compKey.address", "emp[..].compKey.house.address", "emp[..].fakeaddress". Is it possible to search using wildcard at middle, such as: emp[*].address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
$('tr.myClass input[name$=address]').each(function(index){
    alert((this).val());
});
```

to:

```
$('tr.myClass input[name$=address]').each(function(index){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

You are missing `$` in your code:

```
alert($(this).val());
  ____^____  // missing in your code
```

**UPDATE #1**

Since you want to iterate the `input` tag with `name ="emp[..].address"` only but not `emp[..].compKey.address`, you can do this:

```
var $address = $('tr.myClass input[name$=address]:not(input[name$="compKey.address"])');
$address.each(function(index){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

**UPDATE #2**

In case, you have lots of elements which ends with same name, you can do this:

```
var $address = $('tr.myClass input[name$="].address"]');
$address.each(function(index){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: thanks, but what if there are many input tags with name that ended with "address" ? It will be so inconvenient if I had to put so many conditions. Is it possible to search using wildcard at middle, such as: emp[*].address ?